# Nginx running or not?

Tags: linux, service, nginx, debian

I was surprised because the:

```
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

when starting Nginx, so I supposed that Nginx or other was running in the port. I've tested with:

```
lsof -i :80                         
COMMAND   PID     USER   FD   TYPE DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
nginx   13557 www-data    8u  IPv4 100729      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
nginx   13558 www-data    8u  IPv4 100729      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

so yes, Nginx was working and in fact web pages are running. All perfect but...not!

How can be possible this?

```
service nginx status
[FAIL] nginx is not running ... failed!
```

Not running? But I can't start any other instance because it's running! What's happening?

The same when restarting:

```
service nginx restart
Restarting nginx: Enter PEM pass phrase:
Enter PEM pass phrase:
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:80 failed (98: Address already in use)
nginx: [emerg] bind() to 0.0.0.0:443 failed (98: Address already in use)
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4):

Check if nginx is running with:

```
ps aux | grep nginx
```

if nginx process exists, then it's running for sure. What you verified with lsof only proves that 80 port is occupied by certain process (for instance, apache httpd, or some other http servers). If nginx process is not running and yet 80 port is being used, which also explains why you can't start your nginx. In this scenario, you need to lookup in your process list to see which web server is already running. Kill it and restart nginx, it should be then working fine.

Comment: Sorry not to answer before.

Nginx wasn't running and no other web servers. Finally it worked after removing the PEM :/.

Thanks!

Comment: you can also check if you have a default page being served with the local IP `curl -m 10 127.0.0.1` or a public one